# Call Method With multiple arguments

Tags: objective-c, methods, arguments

To call a method with multiple arguments...my method name is getDataToDisplay. I have a compilation error.

```
+ (void) getDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath :(NSString*)filter {
}


 [LettureProve getDataToDisplay: [self getDBPath] :filter];
```

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`;  that is reserved for a special case and this isn't it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the name of the second parameter

```
+ (void) getDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath filter:(NSString*)filter {
}

 [LettureProve getDataToDisplay: [self getDBPath] filter:filter];
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly problems should not exist :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
+ (void) getDataToDisplayWithPath:(NSString *)dbPath andFilter:(NSString*)filter {
}
```